# Personal diary webapp

Tags: web-apps, privacy, hosted, diary

I look for a personal diary service (website) that keeps me anonymous and provides privacy options.

It should have the following features:

- An option to ask always for the username and password
- An option to automatically sign-off if I ware inactive for a while
- An option to encrypt all my posts
- Right-to-left languages support

Comment: "encrypt all my posts": So that only you can read the posts, do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @nic yes, that's right.